# How can I create cartoon green grass for covering a sphere?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects

I've searched a lot about how to create grass for a sphere. I analyzed some pictures from different games.

I can copy what I've found but it's important to know the methods because here I have a sphere to cover with grass rather than flat ground.

Here is a scene from the Farm Frenzy game. I would like to create grass like this.

[image]I

This is my attempt:

1. My first method is using a sketch effect and then image tracing

This is the result:

[image]

2. My second method is to use a grass texture, but on a sphere it doesn't seem good.

[image]

Here is another attempt with illustrator, but it doesn't seem like a cartoon

[image]

So, I decided to ask this question to perhaps find a better method for creating grass and cover a sphere with it.

**How can I create cartoon green grass for covering a sphere?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of your 3 attempts are good.

You need to realize that filters, effects, and automated methods only get you so far. There comes a point where you need to stop looking for the "magic button" or "shortcut" to an end product and roll up your sleeves and start some manual effort.

What I would do is take any of your three attempts (probably #2) and start painting in the edges and variations I wanted. Yes, this will take more time, and certainly takes more artistic skill. But in the end it is the only way you're going to get great looking artwork. If artists could all be replaced with a simple 10 step processes we'd all be broke and homeless.

***So TLDR; You need to manually paint or draw after any automated processes.***

Comment: Thank you, I know artistic skills improved by practicing , However,could you introduce some proper tutorial for this  (manually paint) ?

Comment: Hi @N93, Not really. I mean there are semester-long college courses for art and all it entails - shading, color, light, foreshortening, balance, composition, perspective, etc. You would have as much luck as I would Google Searching for basic art tutorials. [This may or may not be helpful.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13045/beginning-with-drawing)